# Bootstrap content with opaque background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just learning Bootstrap and trying to figure out a good way to display content with an opaque background image.  I'm currently using a "well" but don't have to.  I can get the image "inside" the well and opaque but I can't get it "behind" the other content.  Here is a small sample of the html:

```css
.background1{
    background-size:cover;
    opacity: .25;
    max-width: 1130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <img class="img-rounded background1" src="/Images/housing-4-1213183.jpg" alt="housing" />
        <h2>Section Title Here</h2>
        <p>This is just a place holder for text content that would be showed on top of the desired image.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If there is a better class to use for the content please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to get the text on top or underneath the translucent image? Your question is unclear. Reminder: Opaque means "can't see through", translucent means semi-transparent, and transparent, obviously, totally see through.

Comment: The solution, however, since you are trying to use css opacity to adjust the translucency of the image, is to use absolute positioning and z-indexing, so it takes it out of the rendering flow, allowing your "content" to render on top (or below, depending on how the z-indexing is done)

Comment: mix3d I want the image to be "faded" and in the background and the text "on top" not faded.  Is that clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you. Bootstrap doesn't have a component for this, so you're stuck making it yourself.

**How it works:**
By putting the img as the first child in the parent container, it gets drawn first. The `absolute` positioning guarantees it fills the parent container size, and the container's `relative` position means the children's absolute are *relative* to the parent container. (otherwise, the image would be absolute compared to the body, and fill up the entire window). Then, the Text is drawn, and as it is defined AFTER the image, rendered next, drawing on top of the image.

```css
.covered {
  position:relative; /* make a new "render context", so absolute positioning is relative to this parent container */

  padding:30px; /* only needed for this demo */
}

.covered-img {
  background:url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600');
  opacity: .25;

  background-size:cover; /* cover will scale the image so that the smallest dimension = the widest dimension of the box */
  background-position:center; /* vs the top-left that is default */
  
  position:absolute; /* take me out of the render context! let me define my own positioning */
  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0; /* this could also work with width:100%; height:100%;, but is simpler */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 covered">
     <div class="covered-img"></div>
    
     <h3>Dat content doe</h3>
     <p>So much glorious content</p>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: mix3d not sure if you get notified but I deleted the question to clean this one up.  I'll delete this comment once you delete yours.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
.background1 {
background:url('/Images/housing-4-1213183.jpg');
background-size:cover;
opacity: .25;
max-width: 1130px; 
}
```

and

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">            
        <h2>Section Title Here</h2>
        <p>This is just a place holder for text content that would be showed on top of the desired image.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ethercreation, where does the background1 get applied in the html?

Comment: I assume he meant `<div class="row background1">` but that would not work because the opacity will cause the text to be semi-transparent too, because they are children on the div marked with lowered opacity.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the background image (and not the text) to appear translucent try this:

```
.background1 { 
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.3)0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 100%), url("/Images/housing-4-1213183.jpg");
 background-size:cover;
 max-width: 1130px;
}
```

and in the HTML you'd want the div surrounding the content like this:

```
<div class="well">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="background1">
   <h2>Section Title Here</h2>
    <p>This is just a place holder for text content that would be showed on top of the desired image.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he mixed up the terms opaque and translucent; the image should be a background & have transparency, while the text is untouched. That being said, I like the layered background approach! wouldn't show anything underneath, however, if that was what was intended.

Comment: Yeah, which got me using the words incorrectly, ha. Very true, I didn't really factor in that consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Image faded in the background and text on top of it which is not faded. I believe if this is what you are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
              img {
              opacity: 0.5;
              filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
              position: absolute;
              left: 0px;
              top: 0px;
               z-index: -1;
              }

             .container {
             position:relative;
             left:100px;
             top:100px;
              }

             .container h3 {
              position:absolute;
              top:50px;
              left:50px;
               }

         </style>
        </head>
      <body>

         <div class="container">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBK3FmyjIENz16NWEl1iJcIWj8I5n8hs-rl5JPixzw-XppNfKx"   alt="Forest" width="170" height="100">
            <span>
              <h3>Hello
           </span>
         </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the background image css should be **for the container element**, and not as a tag inside the content...

```
<div class="image">
   Text Content <!-- Right -->
</div>

<div>
   <img class="image" />  <!-- Wrong -->
   Text Content
</div>

.image{
   background-image : url(.../);
}
```