# Set the background of the body to an image while using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-5

I am curious how to set the whole webpage background (the body) to an image. Ideally I would like to fade the image a bit so it isn't overpowering.

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image:url("{% static 'portfolio/cherry_blossoms.jpg' %}"),
    }
</style>
```

I attempted to add this within the html body however it returned no result. Note I am using Bootstrap 5.

Comment: Hi Chandler, for clarification, are you trying to make a background image using bootstrap 5 and have the image with a faded appearance? Your question was confusing at first and I do know how to answer the question, I just need some clarity

Comment: Yes Peter, I want to create a background image that acts as a background with a faded appearance for the entire webpage. Does that make sense? I am new to web programming and bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="bg-image" 
     style="background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/041.jpg');
            height: 100vh">
</div>
```

This code snippet above is how you would add a background generally to a webpage. The image used is an example of what the output would look like.

If you look at `height: 100vh;` this is basically saying "use 100% of the available height" while vh is viewport

Now you did want to make it faded, here is an example of a faded background in bootstrap

```css
.covered {
  position: relative;
  /* make a new "render context", so absolute positioning is relative to this parent container */
  padding: 30px;
  /* only needed for this demo */
}

.covered-img {
  background: url('https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2672/3868702369_67d72be6e8.jpg');
  opacity: .25;
  background-size: cover;
  /* cover will scale the image so that the smallest dimension = the widest dimension of the box */
  background-position: center;
  /* vs the top-left that is default */
  position: absolute;
  /* take me out of the render context! let me define my own positioning */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* this could also work with width:100%; height:100%;, but is simpler */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 covered">
    <div class="covered-img"></div>

    <p>Placeholder Text
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Per a helpful Stack overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493964/bootstrap-content-with-opaque-background-image), the code can be explained below

**How it works**: By putting the img as the first child in the parent container, it gets drawn first. The absolute positioning guarantees it fills the parent container size, and the container's relative position means the children's absolute are relative to the parent container. (otherwise, the image would be absolute compared to the body, and fill up the entire window). Then, the Text is drawn, and as it is defined AFTER the image, rendered next, drawing on top of the image.

Now let's apply that faded style to a background image

```css
.covered {
  position: relative;
  /* make a new "render context", so absolute positioning is relative to this parent container */
}

.covered-img {
  background: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/041.jpg');
  opacity: .25;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  /* cover will scale the image so that the smallest dimension = the widest dimension of the box */
  background-position: center;
  /* vs the top-left that is default */
  position: absolute;
  /* take me out of the render context! let me define my own positioning */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* this could also work with width:100%; height:100%;, but is simpler */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 covered">
    <div class="covered-img"></div>
    <p>Placeholder Text
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a helpful article on Bootstrap 5 Image Backgrounds!](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/content-styles/background-image/)